# Users are not showing up when extracted as .BAR File

Tags: weblogic12c, obiee

I'm currently working on Row Level Security and Trying to study the File Contents of the OBIEE Dashboards once exported as .BAR File .

The issue I'm facing is that the newly created User Names are not showing up in the contents of the Extracted .BAR File .
( Folder Path : <.BAR File Root> \content\catalog\root\users )

To add in more, I created two new users namely : User_1 and User_2 .
And I implemented Row Level Security for both . After Extracting it as .BAR and unzipped it , the User_1 Folder is present in the Folder Location and User_2 Folder is not present .

Note : Role Level Security is working fine with both Users as they log in .

I have tried to down the services and again started up the services but haven't made any differences .

I request to give any suggestions to resolve this issue or any other ways to make the changes made in OBIEE reflect .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Which exact version? Which exact command are you running? etc etc

Comment: Hi Chris , Thanks for the reply . The version I'm using is 12.2.1.3.0 . This version supports the API to extract the .BAR Files of the Dashboard Contents . To extract the .BAR Files we referred this Blog : https://www.obieetips.com/2018/04/steps-to-export-and-import-bar-files-in.html

Comment: *exact* means including BP number since I doubt you are using an unpatche .0 release. Oracle fixes things all the time and there were about 10 BPs for .3 so far.
And where is the exact command that you are? Not some blog post.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply , Chris . Step 1 :After Executing wlst.cmd from Location :  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin.             Step 2 : Execute this Command : wls:/offline> listBIServiceInstances('C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/bi')                 Step 3 : Executed below command : 
exportServiceInstance('C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/bi','ssi','/C:/workDir','/C:/exportDir')

Answer (score 0):

Users and credentials are not exported in BAR files
They must be exported/imported separately using the weblogic console

> To export security data to a file:
> In the left pane, select Security Realms and then select the realm whose security data you want to export (for example, myrealm).
> Expand Migration > Export.
> In the Export Directory on Server field, specify the directory on the Administration Server to which to export the security data.
> Click Save.
> The security data is saved in a file in the location you specified.

It looks like you are exporting user **folders**, not users
oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/taskhelp/security/ExportDataFromSecurityRealms.html

Comment: Op has a general misconception in there. He's talking about the user folders in the web catalog but he seems to disregard that these folders only ever get created upon the very first login of the user in the application and not when the user gets created.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply , Victor and Chris . I have exported the .BAR File of Designed OBIEE Dashboards with Object Level Security Applied by referring to this Blog : https://www.obieetips.com/2018/04/steps-to-export-and-import-bar-files-in.html. After unzipping the .BAR File there will be multiple Folders . At the ( <.BAR File Root> \content\catalog\root\users ) File location ,the users I have created should be present but some of the user folder are missing out / not showing up . If you have any suggestion regarding why the Users Folders are not not showing up , Please Reply .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you read the comment above? Users actually have to actively log in to the application for their /users folders to exist. Also they - obviously - must have the correct rights. If they don't have the right to personal storage in the catalog then nothing will be created.

Answer (score 0):

The OBIEE have mentioned that they have removed the Support for Extracting the .BAR Files of the Dashboards from Version 12.2.1.4 .Now I'm able to export the .BAR Files in the Version 12.2.1.3 where they have given a Disclaimer that they will stop the support to extract the .BAR Files in next Version . So , If you are planned to export .BAR Files use Version before 12.2.1.4 .